# Can I use a rewrite rule to send all requests to a single file?

Tags: seo, htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, regular-expression

Can I make a single regular expression for all my RewriteRules?   I'm rewriting everything to a single file and this this acts like a front-controller.

My example:

```
RewriteRule ^de/kontakt/anfahrt$ kontakt_anfahrt.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/contact/approach$ kontakt_anfahrt.html [NC]
```

I don't want to make for every new file a new rule.

Comment: "...new file a new rule" - this depends entirely on the _pattern_ that links these files (ie. URLs). The two rules/URLs you've posted appear to be entirely different, with no discernable pattern - so combining these two _specific_ rules (which you could do) doesn't really benefit you. Please explain more about what it is your are trying to do. Are you rewriting _everything_ to this single file (and this file acts like a _front-controller_)?

Comment: Yeah, im rewriting evertything to a single file and this this acts like a front-controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^de/kontakt/anfahrt$ kontakt_anfahrt.html [NC]
> RewriteRule ^en/contact/approach$ kontakt_anfahrt.html [NC]
> ```
>
> im rewriting evertything to a single file and this this acts like a front-controller.

The above two mod_rewrite rules rewrite the specific URLs `/de/kontakt/anfahrt` and `/en/contact/approach` to your "front-controller". To rewrite *everything* you just need to generalise the regex to match *anything*. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^ kontakt_anfahrt.html [L]
```

The regex `^` simply matches anything, you could also use `.?` (or `.*` - less efficient) here.

(No need for the `NC` flag, since you are matching *everything*. But the `NC` flag was possibly a bad idea in your original directive as it was promoting duplicate content.)

However, the above probably rewrites too much, as it will also rewrite your static resources (CSS, JS and images), unless these are managed by a different host. So, you could modify the above to rewrite everything, excluding `.css`, `.js` and images (`.jpg` and `.png` in this example):

```
RewriteRule !\.(css|js|jpg|png)$ kontakt_anfahrt.html [L]
```

The above rewrites everything providing the requested URL does not end in one of the file extensions mentioned.

However, even this might not be enough if you are serving a multitude of different file types and/or you have other files that need to be served independently of your front-controller (and/or you wish your front-controller to handle more). Then you can exclude any request that maps to a physical file. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !\.(css|js|jpg|png)$ kontakt_anfahrt.html [L]
```

If you need to also exclude directories then add another condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(css|js|jpg|png)$ kontakt_anfahrt.html [L]
```

So, the above states, if the requested URL does not end in one of the stated file extensions (ie. is a static resource) *and* does not map to a physical file *and* does not map to a directory then *internally rewrite* the request to `kontakt_anfahrt.html` in the same directory (depending on the value of the `RewriteBase` directive - if any).

---

However, depending on your requirements, instead of using mod_rewrite/regex above you could simply use the `FallbackResource` directive:

```
FallbackResource /kontakt_anfahrt.html
```

This basically does the same thing. If Apache determines that the requested URL would otherwise result in a 404 then it routes the request to `/kontakt_anfahrt.html`.