# FrontController dosen´t work

Tags: htaccess, url, php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have a example FrontController, its really simple.

index.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
  $requested_page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
  $requested_page = 'home';
}

switch($requested_page) {
   case "blog":
      include(__DIR__."/blog.php");
      break;
   case "home":
      include(__DIR__."/home.php");
      break;
   default:
      include(__DIR__."/help.php");
}
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

But this dosen´t work, i have tried to give the index.php the parameter "page", but this also dont work.

Comment: How were you managing the URL-routing in your other front-controller related question? https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121918/can-i-use-a-rewrite-rule-to-send-all-requests-to-a-single-file

Comment: I think this way is better, because i have only 3 lines in the htaccess-file. Or im wrong?

Comment: It's not really about the number of lines in the `.htaccess` file. The solution I presented in my answer to your [other question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121918/can-i-use-a-rewrite-rule-to-send-all-requests-to-a-single-file) only had 3 lines as well (and only 1 line you used the `FallbackResource` directive). It's just a different method (pros and cons of each). My point really is that if the code (even the original code in your question) was "working" then the _principles_ involved here are in fact the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i have tried to give the index.php the parameter "page"

Although you've not included this in the example you posted - so what you have posted will obviously not work because of this. If your front-controller is dependent on a `page` URL parameter then you need to pass this in the rewritten URL. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I assume you've already included the necessary `RewriteEngine On` directive?

`(.+)` - You don't need to rewrite the empty URL-path, since mod_dir will issue an internal subrequest for `index.php` by default.

The `NC` flag is not required here, because your regex is not case dependent.

`([^?]*)` - The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string. So checking for anything other that `?` in the regex is generally pointless, unless you have a specific requirement?

---

> **UPDATE#1:** ...it still dont work ...maybe because of the path? It is in "localhost/controller"

I assume from this that `index.php` is in the `/controller` subdirectory, ie. `/controller/index.php` and your `.htaccess` file is in the document root, and you are requesting URLs of the form `example.com/blog`. In which case your `RewriteRule` directive should be of the form:

```
RewriteRule (.+) /controller/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

> **UPDATE#2:** ...my `.htaccess` is in the `/controller` directory ... The format is `localhost/controller/filename`.

In that case the above should still work, although you will need to make sure that `MultiViews` is disabled when accessing `/controller/blog`, `.../home` or `.../help` since these map directly to files of the same name but with a `.php` file extension.

MultiViews should not be enabled by default, however, some shared hosts do enable it for some reason. If MultiViews is enabled then you would expect your include file to be requested directly, essentially bypassing your front-controller. ie. request `/blog` and `/blog.php` gets loaded automatically.

If the `.htaccess` file and `index.php` are in the same directory then the *substitution* string can be simplified.

In summary:

```
# Disable MultiViews
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The pattern `.+` specifically matches 1 or more characters, so this naturally excludes requests for the directory itself (ie. `/controller/`). However, mod_dir will handle this and direct the request to `index.php`, providing your `DirectoryIndex` is set correctly.

Comment: First thanks for the new information. But it still dont work if i add the "page" parameter. maybe because of the path? It is in "localhost/controller"

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file and where is `index.php`? Is `/controller` a physical directory? This is quite possibly the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still dont work :/

Comment: And my .htaccess is in the "/controller" directory in "/var/www/html/"

Comment: And what are the format of the URLs you are requesting?

Comment: The format is "localhost/controller/filename"

Comment: Ok, the above should still work in that case, although the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ can be simplified to `index.php?page=$1` (no slash prefix). However, you also need to make sure that `MultiViews` is disabled. When you say it "doesn't work" - what happens exactly? Do you get an error? The include file opens directly? Nothing ie. a 404? (With MultiViews enabled I would expect your front-controller to be bypassed and the include file would be included directly.)

Comment: I've updated my answer.